# Node/Express - PowerShell : Invoke-WebRequest : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'content-type: application/json'

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I wrote a sample REST code which I am shared below.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Listening to port 3000'));

app.post('/hello', (req, res)=>{
    console.log('Headers : ',req.headers);
    console.log('Method : ',req.method);
    console.log('Body : ',req.body);
    res.send('Received POST Request ..!!\n');
});
```

I am trying to make the POST call using below curl command.

> curl --header 'content-type: application/json'
> http://localhost:3000/hello --data '{"foo": "bar"}'

I am getting the following error while trying to access POST using curl.

[image: Error Screen]